# How to make a custom semi-circular progress indicator with terminator?

Tags: swift, calayer, cashapelayer

I'd like to make a custom semi-circular inverted progress indicator that looks like this:

[image]

I've tried with `CAShapeLayer` for background, progress line and progress line terminator (small white circle). I'm using `ring.strokeEnd = progress` to define where the progress line ends.

How to add the line terminator to the end of progress line?

Here's my code (note: I've hardcoded the position for the small white circle, as I don't know how to properly implement this):

```
class AKBezierson: UIView {

    var ringBackground: CAShapeLayer!
    var ring: CAShapeLayer!
    var ringTerminator: CAShapeLayer!
    var innerRect: CGRect!
    var radius: CGFloat { return min(innerRect.width, innerRect.height) / 2 }
    var progress: CGFloat  = 0.8 { didSet { updateLayerProperties() } }

    private struct Const {
        static let gap: CGFloat = 10
        static let width: CGFloat = 3.0
    }

    override func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()

        innerRect = CGRectInset(bounds, Const.width / 2 + Const.gap, Const.width / 2 + Const.gap)

        let path = UIBezierPath()
        path.addArcWithCenter(
            CGPointMake(bounds.width / 2, bounds.height / 2),
            radius: radius,
            startAngle: CGFloat(0),
            endAngle: CGFloat(M_PI),
            clockwise: true)

        if (ringBackground == nil) {
            ringBackground = CAShapeLayer()
            layer.addSublayer(ringBackground)
            ringBackground.path = path.CGPath
            ringBackground.fillColor = nil
            ringBackground.lineWidth = Const.width
            ringBackground.strokeColor = UIColor(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.5).CGColor
        }
        ringBackground.frame = ringBackground.bounds

        if (ring == nil) {
            ring = CAShapeLayer()
            layer.addSublayer(ring)
            ring.path = path.CGPath
            ring.fillColor = nil
            ring.lineWidth = Const.width
            ring.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            ring.strokeEnd = progress
        }
        ring.frame = ring.bounds

        if (ringTerminator == nil) {   // small circle
            ringTerminator = CAShapeLayer()
            layer.addSublayer(ringTerminator)
            let terminatorCircle = UIBezierPath(ovalInRect: CGRectMake(15, 83, 12, 12))
            ringTerminator.path = terminatorCircle.CGPath
            ringTerminator.fillColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
            ringTerminator.lineWidth = Const.width
            ringTerminator.strokeColor = UIColor.whiteColor().CGColor
        }
        ringTerminator.frame = ringTerminator.bounds

        updateLayerProperties()
    }

    func updateLayerProperties () {
        if !(ring == nil) {
            ring.strokeEnd = progress
        }
    }
}
```

I've also tried to calculate the point where the progress line ends and move the line terminator to a new position every time the progress changed, but I was not satisfied with the animation since the terminator was trying to reach the new position following the shortest (strait) path.

Comment: You might consider rotating the terminator around the center of the ring, rather than trying to move it, so you could get motion along the circle for free.

Comment: Yes, thak you @jtbandes. This should be the right direction. Now I  have issues with rotation. I'm using `ringTerminator.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.5, 0.5)` and `ringTerminator.transform = CATransform3DMakeRotation(CGFloat(-M_PI / 4), 0, 0, 1)` , but seems like I'm having issues with layer bounds.

Comment: @Andrej did u create it ?